# IronPython Webframework

Tags: python, ironpython

There seem to be many excellent web frameworks for Python.  Has anyone used any of these (Pylons, Web2Py, Django) with IronPython?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django [has been run on IronPython](http://unbracketed.org/2008/mar/16/pycon-2008-django-now-plays-dark-side/) before, but as a proof-of-concept. I know the IronPython team are interested in Django support as a metric for Python-compatibility.

Somewhat related is the possibility to use [IronPython with ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/09/23/refreshing-asp.net-dynamic-language-support.aspx), which is probably more mature.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to read [this](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_thread/thread/857f9d7bc5c25822/278c5a8e209c83e5?lnk=gst&q=ironpython#278c5a8e209c83e5)

Basically web2py code runs unmodified and out of the box but with IronPython but

- no CSV module (so no database IO)
- no third party database drivers (not even SQLite, so no databases at all)
- no built-in web server (unless you cripple it by removing signals and logging)

This is because csv, signals, logging and sqlite are not present in IronPython.
An you can see from the thread above there is work underway to find ways around.

web2py also runs unmodified on Jython 2.5 beta, without any known limitation, except for a bug with regular expressions in Jython that makes it choke on some templates (re.compile(...).finditer goes in a loop). We are working to find a way around for this as well.

Answer (score -3):

we2py released Feb 5, 2009

http://www.web2py.com

- Includes a Database Abstraction Layer that works with SQLite, MySQL,
  PostgreSQL, FireBird, MSSQL, Oracle, AND the Google App Engine.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question in hand... So do you know whether it works with IronPython or doesn't it?